# GIT Shortest Commands

Tags: git

Im trying to figure out the git command so I dont have to keep calling whole entire URL, can anyone help me?

It was something like:

```
$ git remote add git@github.com:JREAM/library.git
$ git push -u origin master
$ git pull
```

I know that's not correct, but does anyone know the shortest way to add a repository to my git file so that I can type the **minimum amount of commands**?

Comment: are you looking for `git remote add origin git@github.com:JREAM/library.git`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git remote add *origin* git@github.com:JREAM/library.git

Comment: Actually, if you did `push -u` for the branch once (i.e. branch is tracked), you may simply say `git pull`.

Comment: You should really work yourself through some tutorials to grasp the basic concepts. The [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book and [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in particular is a good read.